# Changing the R studio shortcut to switch tabs

Tags: rstudio

By default, one can use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd>/<kbd>right</kbd> to switch between tabs. Is it possible to change this shortcut?

I don't see it in the list of keybboard shortcuts:

[image]

Comment: Open Next Tab and Open Previous Tab? It looks like the Ctrl+Alt+<direction> is just an additional one that is unlisted. But you can still modify the shortcut to your liking using those that I mentioned.

Comment: @Dason thanks  it works. I didn't expect that a different keyboard shortcut  would be listed, and "previous/next" is quite a misnomer. You're welcome to convert your comment into anwer.

Comment: Why do you think it's a misnomer? Seems like the natural description to me.

Comment: @Dason previous to me means previously visited. I'd say Left/right

Comment: Fair enough. Maybe submit an issue with RStudio to let them know you think that would be better phrasing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to modify the "Open Next Tab" and "Open Previous Tab" shortcuts.  The shortcuts you have listed are different from mine but either way the Ctrl+Alt+ work for me even though the listed shortcuts are Ctrl+F11 and Ctrl+F12.  Modifying these shortcuts allows you to use whatever you want to switch between tabs.

Comment: I can't modify them to `Ctrl + Page Up` and `Ctrl + Page Down` tho, just `Page Up`/`Page Down` is fine.